# Accessing parameter/dynamic URL property in router meta for dynamic page title?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So I have for example this route in my routes:

```
{ name: 'user', path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: { default: true, sidebar: false }, meta: { showFooter: false, title: `Viewing User ${route.params.id}` } }
```

I'm essentially wanting to access the id parameter of the URL, to set the title of the page, but I do not want to do it via the component.

Using ${route.params.id} returns undefined, is there an object I can access that will give me the same result? I'm relatively new to Vue and Vue-router, so unsure if this is possible or not.

Maybe I **should** be setting this in the component, and if so I'm happy to learn why this is the better way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this and just use a computed property in your component.

```js
computed: {
  title() { return `Viewing User ${this.$route.params.id}` }
}
```

If you want to abstract your implementation (for multiple components, etc), set your meta data in `beforeRouteUpdate`.  Then you can access `this.$route`.

```js
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // called when the route that renders this component has changed,
    // but this component is reused in the new route.
    // For example, for a route with dynamic params `/foo/:id`, when we
    // navigate between `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, the same `Foo` component instance
    // will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens.
    // *** has access to `this` component instance. ***
  },
```

-> **has access to `this` component instance**

Comment: Does that not then mean the page title is updated **before** the route has changed, therefore all of your browser history is off by one?

Comment: Also on another note - this doesn't seem to allow you to use parameters in the route metatag, so you would have to have to loop through params and check if the route & param matched what you wanted to set it to for a dynamic title and then set accordingly? It is just this page I want to set it with the parameter, not all pages which seems to seem a little hacky.

Comment: If you want to use `this.$route`, you need to get it from `beforeRouteUpdate`, or the component (`created()` will work).  `beforeRouteUpdate` will be invoked **after the route change**, and after any params change.  Can't you modify the route meta directly in the hook?

Comment: BTW, why are you not just creating a computed property in your component?  `title(){ return `Viewing User ${this.$route.params.id}`}`

Comment: If that is the recommended way to do it then I can do that :) I just thought it made more sense being in the route file and then it's all contained in one area rather than having to have the title property in each main page component

Comment: If this is just 1 component, the computed property is ABSOLUTELY the way to go!

Comment: the plan is to use it across the entire SPA, with the title updating per main component

Comment: You can always create a mixin and add the computed `title` to all your main components.